# Column list VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I already have data on the spreadsheet in excel organized in 4 columns, how can show the whole data in a listbox (column list) on a userform, then how can I found the way to extract the value of a selected item for example, I select with a double click the first item (1 , 2) it shows me the value of the second column (2)
I use this for show it

```
For r = 1 To Lista.ListCount
    If Lista.Selected(r) Then

        MsgBox r + 1
        MsgBox "You selected row #" & Sheets("View2").Cells(r + 2, rangE("View2_CN").Column)

    End If
Next
```

Comment: What are you asking? It shows you the value of the second column from your range. What do you want it to show in the MsgBox prompt?